# Why can I successfully ping stats.nba.com and not stats.nba.com/stats

Tags: dns, ping

Very new to Unix and experimenting with a Digital Ocean droplet. Why can I successfully `ping stats.nba.com` whereas `ping stats.nba.com` results in `ping: unknown host stats.nba.com/stats`

Comment: As far as i know...you ping `hosts`, not `paths` or `hosts + paths`. You may try curl o wget to "ping" a host+path and parse the http code in the response.

Comment: I agree with @bistoco.  I have just tried pinging a page that does exist `www.nba.com/standings` and it too returns `Name or service not known`.  So you will not be able to ping a path.  Only the host can be pinged.

Comment: @bistoco that sounds like it should be an answer!

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know...you ping `hosts`, not `paths` or `hosts + paths`.

You may try `curl` o `wget` to "ping" a `host+path` and parse the http code in the response.

UPDATE 1:
**You may want to check the path.**
For [stats.nba.com/stats](http://stats.nba.com/stats) , host exists, but path doesn't.

Doing a `curl` call, i get 2 redirects
1.- http to https
2.- `/stats/` to `/error/`, which return `200 OK` instead of the expected `404 Not Found`-

```
curl -sSL -D - stats.nba.com/stats -o /dev/null 2>&1 | grep -E '^HTTP|^Location'
```

Filter headers

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://stats.nba.com/stats
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://stats.nba.com/error/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```